# Issue with DQL outer join

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT r.pLastName, r.pFirstName, r.ppLocation, a.createdDate, a.appointmentDate, a.hour, a.minute, a.ampm, p.firstName, p.lastName, a.reason, pl.firstName as oncologyPhysicianFirstName, pl.lastName as oncologyPhysicianLastName
FROM MainReferralCaptureBundle:Appointment a, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Referral r, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Physician p
RIGHT OUTER JOIN MainReferralCaptureBundle:PhysicansLocations pl WITH pl.physicansLocationsId = r.ppName
WHERE a.referralId = r.id
AND r.submittedBy = :user
AND r.rpId = p.id
ORDER BY a.appointmentDate DESC
```

I am getting the following error:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 366: Error: Expected end of string, got 'RIGHT'
```

If I do:

```
SELECT r.pLastName, r.pFirstName, r.ppLocation, a.createdDate, a.appointmentDate, a.hour, a.minute, a.ampm, p.firstName, p.lastName, a.reason, pl.firstName as oncologyPhysicianFirstName, pl.lastName as oncologyPhysicianLastName
        FROM MainReferralCaptureBundle:Appointment a, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Referral r, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Physician p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MainReferralCaptureBundle:PhysicansLocations pl WITH pl.physicansLocationsId = r.ppName
        WHERE a.referralId = r.id
        AND r.submittedBy = :user
        AND r.rpId = p.id
        ORDER BY a.appointmentDate DESC
```

I get:

```
ORA-00904: "R0_"."PP_NAME": invalid identifier
```

I am not sure what is happening. `ppName` is a valid identifier. Please note that I am using Oracle as my back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I had to change the order in my FROM clause:

```
FROM MainReferralCaptureBundle:Appointment a, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Physician p, MainReferralCaptureBundle:Referral r
```

now everything works.